# Firebug - Console - Filter information shown

Tags: javascript, console, firebug

I use firebug a lot but but really just the basics and I don't pretend to understand it in any detail though it is very useful.

I would like to just show the console.log entries that I have inserted in the javascript and not the other stuff. You can filter what is shown and I thought that "DebugInfo" may show console.log entries but it doesn't.

The problem with reading the console is that I have ajax requests every few milliseconds and these fill up the page in no time and it starts scrolling and it is difficult to spot the relevant info passing by.

Ideally I would like to filter out all the GET http...... and just have the console.log info, is there a way to do this or a different approach that would make it easier for me to debug? A pause button would work but having googled that it doesn't seem to be possible.

My application is on a webserver on a microchip so I don't want to set break points as I would need to reprogram often as I tested different things and that takes too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the word "Console" in Firebug you should see a little down arrow. If you click that you get an option for "Show XMLHttpRequests". Untick that and try again.

[image]

You can also filter in Chrome's Developer Tools by clicking the blue filter icon.

Comment: Thank you, that will make things much easier! That was quite simple, I really should have spotted that!

Comment: Note that there is a [detailed description of the Console panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel), which also mentions that.